# How can I display the title from a marker as reference in another item, such as textview?

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

I 'm trying to display the title from a marker in Textview, and simultaneously passing LatLng for this marker so as to use it in another Button.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null);


            TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());


            return view;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As your question is currently written, it is hard to tell what issue you are facing. Please edit your question and elaborate more on what issue you have and what you have already tried to solve it. If you need more inspiration, have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks!! Tapping on a marker I want to take its title and display it into a TextView parsing its LatLng too. I 've found how this is made by a button to another item, but I 've no idea how I can do it via marker.

Comment: Tbh, I am not very familiar with the android maps library  What are you getting when you call `marker.getTitle()`?

Comment: thanks for your help :) Actually, it 's interrupted repeatedly. It shows nothing